# Why do Pipes Hang When I try to Read Them?

Tags: c#, .net-core, pipe

I am making a program that starts a child process and communicates via anonymous pipes. When I read from a pipe, the program hangs at the first `ReadLine()` call as seen in the following code method:

```
// Reads messages sent from module's process via anonymous pipe
        internal string[] ReadPipe() {
            try {
                Log.Verbose("Checking read pipe");

                // Check for sync message and return null if there is no message to receive
                string pipeMessage = _pipeInReader.ReadLine(); // HANGS ON THIS LINE
                if(pipeMessage == null || !pipeMessage.StartsWith("SYNC")) {
                    Log.Verbose("No message found in pipe");
                    return null;
                }

                // Return array of message lines
                Log.Verbose("Received message from module {ModuleName}", _fileInfo.Name);
                List<string> pipeMessageLines = new();
                do {
                    pipeMessage = _pipeInReader.ReadLine();
                    pipeMessageLines.Add(pipeMessage);
                    Log.Debug(pipeMessage);
                } while(pipeMessage != null && !pipeMessage.StartsWith("END"));

                return pipeMessageLines.ToArray();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.Error(e.ToString());
                return null;
            }
        }
```

The code I am using to write to the pipe is the following:

```
// Sends a message to module's process via anonymous pipe
        public static void WritePipe(string message) {
            try {
                Log.Verbose("Sending \"{Message}\" to kit pipe", message);
                
                // Send sync message and wait for module process to receive it
                Log.Verbose("Waiting for pipe drain");
                _pipeOutWriter.Write("SYNC");
                _pipeOut.WaitForPipeDrain();

                // Send the specified message
                Log.Verbose("Pipe drained. Sending message");
                _pipeOutWriter.Write(message);
                _pipeOutWriter.Write("END");

            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.Error(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Why does it hang at that `ReadLine()` line?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a proper [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it's impossible to say for sure. However, one glaring problem with your code is that when you write to the `_pipeOutWriter` object, you don't call `Flush()`. Assuming that's a `TextWriter`, by default it's going to buffer the data until the internal buffer is full, and not send anything to the underlying `Stream` until then.

By calling `Flush()`, you force it to flush its internal buffer and send the data right away.

If that does not address your question, please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67552559/edit) to improve it, making sure to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and any additional details about what you've tried so far to fix the problem and what specifically you need help with.